# SQL IF Statement with two selects, result should value of statement #1 or #2

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have a complex sql statement with some selects of seperate tables. Here is an excerpt of this:

```
...
(
    SELECT
        SUM(`billvalue`)
    FROM
        `dc_bills`
    WHERE
        `ordersid` = `o`.`ordersid`
    AND
        `type` = 'O'
    AND
        `type2` = 'K'
) AS `finalbillvalue`,
(
    SELECT
        SUM(`billvalue`)
    FROM
        `dc_bills`
    WHERE
        `ordersid` = `o`.`ordersid`
    AND
        `type` = 'O'
    AND
        `type2` = 'E'
) AS `billvalue`
...
```

There are 2 types of bills: final bills and normal bills. Final bills contains the complete value of the order, normal bills are for single settlements.

I need:
When finalbillvalue < 1 THEN choose billvalue ELSE choose finalbillvalue.

Can i get this in the statement? My tries failed with sql error "there is no column with finalbillvalue".

Comment: finalbillvalue here is created as a table. Try to pull in as a column in some table and then you would be able to use it in sql query

Comment: Why should finalbillvalue be a table? It is a column named finalbillvalue and with php i can ouput ist value. But i want compare the 2 values of select statement #1 and #2 and set in example endbillvalue = finalbillvalue OR billvalue

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT t.*, IF(finalbillvalue < 1, billvalue, finalbillvalue) FROM (<your current select statement>) t`?

Comment: ' It is a column named finalbillvalue' - not so. ' a subquery in a SELECT statement FROM clause is a derived table:' ...'[AS] tbl_name clause is mandatory because every table in a FROM clause must have a name.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html which you have but you haven't assigned a name to the column within the subquery and presumably haven't referred to it later.

Comment: And you appear to be using an implicit (comma) join thereby generating a cartesian product.